# Promise.then() not waiting

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable

Promise.then() is not stopping the 3 events, *this.events, this.tmEvents, this.totalEvents* from logging before the promises complete. If I log this.tmEvents in the getEvents function, it will appear after those 3 events. Is there a way to hold these functions off? I tried using async/ await but still got the same result.

```
//this.data.tmevents (Dataservice)
  public tmEventsSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  tmEvents = this.tmEventsSource.asObservable();
  newTmevents(tmEvents) {
    this.tmEventsSource.next(tmEvents);
  }


  async fetchEvents() {
    await this.getEvents();
    await this.getTmEvents();
    this.data.tmEvents.subscribe(tmEvents => {
        this.totalEvents = this.totalEvents.concat(this.events);
        this.totalEvents = this.totalEvents.concat(tmEvents);
        console.log(this.events);
        console.log(tmEvents);
        console.log(this.totalEvents);
        this.shuffle(this.totalEvents);
    });

  async getTmEvents() {
    const storedTMEvents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.TM_EVENTS));
    if (storedTMEvents == null) {
        try {
            const res = await this.getUserLocationServ();
            await this.getTmEventsServ(res);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    } else {
        this.data.newTmevents(storedTMEvents);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a subscription inside the `then`. If you need to wait till `this.tmEvent` is assigned the value, then you need to move the following statements inside the subscription.

Comment: @MichaelD So that works but for some reason it gets logged twice. The first time, it logs the subscription value that did not get updated and again when the value is updated

Comment: Probably `this.data.tmEvents` emits twice before the control is returned from the function. Could you please update the modified code in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return them to create a chain, and try to use `async / await` to simplify the chain.

Below you can find an example that waits everything and is more readable.

```js
async fetchEvents() {
    await this.getEvents();
    await this.getTmEvents();
    this.data.tmEvents.subscribe(tmEvents => {
        this.tmEvents = tmEvents;
        this.totalEvents = this.totalEvents.concat(this.events);
        this.totalEvents = this.totalEvents.concat(this.tmEvents);
        console.log(this.events);
        console.log(this.tmEvents);
        console.log(this.totalEvents);
        this.shuffle(this.totalEvents);
    });
}

async getTmEvents() {
    const storedTMEvents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.TM_EVENTS));
    if (storedTMEvents == null) {
        try {
            const res = await this.getUserLocationServ();
            await this.getTmEventsServ(res);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    } else {
        this.data.newTmevents(storedTMEvents);
    }
}
```

Comment: So This did fix the order, but I am receiving a subscriber as the value of tmEvents

Comment: might you share its code? Perhaps should it be `this.data.tmEvents().toPromise()`?

Comment: Yeah I changed that to subscribe to the response

Comment: Sorry, I meant source code of `this.data.tmEvents`.

Comment: Ah, in your code it will be subscription, it should be `await this.data.tmEvents.toPromise();` as it's written in my answer.

Comment: I've removed the comment to avoid confusions.

Comment: Perfect just edited this.tmEvents to tmevents. thank you

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code to set `this.tmEvents`